# why can't I finish creating a virtual device using my system Images in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

when I open the system manager to create a virtual device, select a device definition and proceed to select a system image, I stop at selecting the system image and I can not press the next button

I tried uninstalling the application(Android Studio) and re-installing it as  I suspected that the problem was within the installation of the application files but when I re-installed it the same problem repeated and so I can not create any virtual device